# Mock a model method in Django

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, django-testing, django-tests

I'm just getting started with `Mock` for testing Django apps without touching the db. I can successfully mock my model objects in my tests, but I'm a little confused as to how to deal with model methods which involve objects.

As an example I have this in my models.py:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   category = models.ForeignKey(
       SkillCategory, default=None, null=True, blank=True
   )

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    skill = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, default=None)
    avatar = models.URLField(
        max_length=400, default=None, null=True, blank=True
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def update_skills(self, cleaned_skills):
        for s in cleaned_skills:
            skill, created = Skill.objects.get_or_create(title=s)
            self.skill.add(skill)
```

So far in my re-factored tests I have done this:

```
class ProfileTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # mock user
        self.user = mock.Mock(spec=User)
        self.user.username = "john"
        self.user.email = "johndoe@hotmail.com"
        self.user.password = "pass"
        # mock profile
        self.userprofile = mock.Mock(spec=UserProfile)
        self.userprofile.user = self.user
        # mock skill category
        self.skill_category = mock.Mock(spec=SkillCategory)
        self.skill_category.title = "foo"
        # mock skill
        self.skill = mock.Mock(spec=Skill)
        self.skill.title = "ninja"
        self.skill.category = self.skill_category

    def test_skillcategory_created(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.skill.category.title, 'foo')

    def test_skill_created(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.skill.title, 'ninja')

    ...
    # and so on
```

In my old tests, which use the db, I had this to test my model method:

```
    ...

    def test_update_skills(self):
        cleaned_skills = ['mysql', 'unix']
        self.userprofile.update_skills(cleaned_skills)
        skills = self.userprofile.skill.values_list('title', flat=True)
        self.assertTrue('mysql' in skills)
```

I'm scratching my head on how I should refactor this line:

```
self.userprofile.update_skills(cleaned_skills)
```

to take advantage of `Mock`.

Answer (score 6):

You can mock the `get_or_create()` method, as well as the `skill` relation to let your test run without accessing the database.

```
def test_update_skills(self):
    def mock_get_or_create(title):
        return title, True
    mock_skill = set()
    with mock.patch('analytics.models.Skill.objects.get_or_create',
                    mock_get_or_create), \
            mock.patch.object(UserProfile, 'skill', mock_skill):
        userprofile = UserProfile()

        cleaned_skills = ['mysql', 'unix']
        userprofile.update_skills(cleaned_skills)

    self.assertEqual({'mysql', 'unix'}, mock_skill)
```

I'm helping out with the [`django_mock_queries` project](https://github.com/stphivos/django-mock-queries) that helps provide a bunch of Django queryset features without accessing the database. It's made a bunch of our tests way faster.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your test looks strange
2. You can test model methods without creating records in database, just don't use .create() or .save():

   ```
   def test_my_method(self):
       my_model = MyModel(someattr='someval', ...)
       self.assertEqual(my_model.my_method(), ...)
   ```
3. Sometimes it is good decision to mock .save() method to disable creating records in database and speedup tests. See few examples of how You can use mock in tests: http://nanvel.name/2014/04/testing-django-application#patchmock

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't think of just not saving the object. This can be very useful for testing models who have a `date_added` field set to `auto_now_add=True`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Mixer](https://github.com/klen/mixer):

```
from mixer.backend.django import mixer

skill = mixer.blend(Skill, category__title='foo')
userprofile = mixer.blend(UserProfile, user__username='john')
```